# Qt cannot include ui header file

Tags: qt

I am try to build a simple qt project. For the project, the source file `main.cpp` is created using a general c++ editor, and the `.ui` file is created using qt design form, and they both are placed in the same directory. Then a `.pro` file is created, which reference both the `main.cpp` and `.ui` file.

The `.pro` file is here:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = gotocell
SOURCES += main.cpp
FORMS += gotocelldialog.ui
QT += widgets
```

And the `main.cpp` is:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_gotocelldialog.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Ui::GoToCellDialog ui;
    QDialog *dialog = new QDialog;
    ui.setupUi(dialog);
    dialog->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

This follows the example code: [gotocell1](https://github.com/mutse/qt5-book-code/blob/master/chap02/gotocell1/main.cpp)

But this line of codes

```
#include "ui_gotocelldialog.h"
```

causes the error: `no such file or directory`.

I am using QtCreator4.5. It is said that QtCreator will automatically generate the header files for the created ui [how to create header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728470/how-to-create-header-file-and-source-file-of-a-ui-file-in-qtdesigner).  What is going wrong here?

Comment: go to the `Build` menu, and select `Run qmake` and run again

Answer (score 3):

The generated source file is created and stored within your build folder.  It does not get added to your project tree view as part of QtCreator.  You can find your build folder directory by looking under Tools->Options->Build&Run.

I usually add the generated files to my own project tree view as I usually like to inspect it, but since is auto-generated from the ui file, it is not committed to version control.